# JSF 1.2 response capture including resources

Tags: jsf, resources, richfaces, wrapper

I am using JSF 1.2 with RichFaces. Is it possible to mimic the "Save as" of a web browser client? To be more precise, I want to add a "Download zip" on a page. The purpose is to generate a zip archive containing the HTML generated page with all necessary files to open that page with a correct layout.

I succeeded in the past to capture the HTML page by means of a `HttpResponseWrapper`.
But as soon as the page contains RichFaces components, some JS and images are required for a correct display. How could I get those resources to add them in the zip?

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org). It can easily find CSS/JS/image elements by jQuery-like CSS selectors and give you the resource URLs back so that you can download them individually.

```
InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
// ... Save webpage itself.

Document document = Jsoup.parse(savedWebPage, "UTF-8", url);

for (Element stylesheet : document.select("link[rel=stylesheet]")) {
    InputStream input = new URL(stylesheet.absUrl("href")).openStream();
    // ... Save individual stylesheet file.
}

for (Element script : document.select("script[src]")) {
    InputStream input = new URL(script.absUrl("src")).openStream();
    // ... Save individual script file.
}

for (Element img : document.select("img[src]")) {
    InputStream input = new URL(img.absUrl("src")).openStream();
    // ... Save individual image file.
}
```

CSS background images are not taken into account. You could consider a CSS parser like [SAC](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/SAC/) on every individual CSS file.

Comment: Thank you very much, this must do the job !!